# Working with columns having dot(.) in their name using GQL

Tags: google-app-engine, gql, gqlquery, objectify

I use Objectify for datastore operations in my GAE/Java application. I have used Objectify's @Embeded facility in a couple of places in my project. Objectify automatically flattens the nested objects within the entity marked by @Embeded notation using the . separator. Thus I have ended up with column names like entity.embededObject.Field

For example I have an entity 'Person' in my data store with two columns `name` and `address.email`.

I want to filter through Person in the datastore viewer by writing a simple GQL query.
But the following query fails with a syntax error:

```
SELECT * FROM Person where address.email='mail@gmail.com'
```

whereas the following works as it should

```
SELECT * FROM Person where name='Joe'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [UPDATE] The issue is addressed in the 1.5.3 pre-release of GAE-java http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2584

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GQL currently doesn't support this - only 'word' characters are supported. You should definitely file this as a bug in the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry).

Comment: Then this is a serious drawback of using @Embeded notation in objectify, the documentation never mentioned.

Comment: @Ashwin Actually, it's a bug in the GQL parser - it should definitely have support for a quoted syntax for accessing these parameters - which is why I suggested you file a bug.

Comment: Found a bug report on a similar issue in issue tracker. http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2584

 Looks like some work has already begun on the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Tested today, it is possible to run the following with backquotes

```
SELECT * FROM `your.kind`
```

I believe this holds true for any parameter, but please correct me if I am wrong.